# How to target divs with other content using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a bunch of divs with some text in them.
I am trying to create a simple function that targets divs with a specific text and gives them a class. I also want to give the divs with other text a common class.

I have managed to target the divs with the specific texts, but I cant figure out how to target the divs with other texts.

This is the HTML

```
<h1>The divs</h1>

  <div>High</div>
  <div>Low</div>
  <div>Medium</div>

  <div>Hit 'em high</div>
  <div>Medium rare</div>

  <div>A funky name</div>
```

and this is the function

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
function classChanger () {
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].textContent === 'High') {
            divs[i].classList.add('high');
        } if (divs[i].textContent === 'Medium') {
            divs[i].classList.add('medium');
        } if (divs[i].textContent === 'Low') {
            divs[i].classList.add('low');
        } if (divs[i].textContent === 'anything') {
            divs[i].classList.add('none');
        } 
    }
};

classChanger();
```

I have tried to use several more if statemets with !== 'High' and so on, but they just overwrite the previous code.

So I am just wondering, how do I target the last three divs and give them the class none?
I have tried googling but I dont think im googling the right question, thats why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `High`, `Medium`, and `Low` to an array. As you loop over the elements check to see if array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the text (and set the class to the lowercase version of the text), otherwise add a `none` class.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

const range = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'];

function classChanger() {
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    const text = divs[i].textContent;
    if (range.includes(text)) {
      divs[i].classList.add(text.toLowerCase());
    } else {
      divs[i].classList.add('none');
    }
  }
}

classChanger();
```

```css
.high { color: red; }
.medium { color: orange; }
.low { color: yellow; }
.none { color: darkgray; }
```

```html
<div>High</div>
<div>Low</div>
<div>Medium</div>

<div>Hit 'em high</div>
<div>Medium rare</div>

<div>A funky name</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use an `else if` statement like this:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
function classChanger() {
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].textContent === "High") {
      divs[i].classList.add("high");
    } else if (divs[i].textContent === "Medium") {
      divs[i].classList.add("medium");
    } else if (divs[i].textContent === "Low") {
      divs[i].classList.add("low");
    } else {
      divs[i].classList.add("none");
    }
  }
}

classChanger();
```

Comment: Hi, Ahmed. Thanks for your answer. It works but I chose the previous one because I think its less code to write in the long run, so its the "better answer". I would like your comment if I could but I got 2 low points to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target elements based on content, you first need to create a function for such purpose like:

```js
function queryElementsWithFilter(selector, filterCallback) {
  if (typeof selector !== 'string') throw new TypeError('param 1 must be a string')
  if (typeof filterCallback !== 'function') throw new TypeError('param 2 must be a function')

  const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
  return nodes.filter(filterCallback)
}
```

Now you can get the elements you want and do anything with them.

```js
const textTokens = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']

textTokens.forEach(textToken => {
  const divCollection = queryElementsWithFilter(
    'div',
    node => node.textContent === textToken
  )

  divCollection.forEach(div => div.classList.add(textToken.toLowerCase()))
})

const unmatchedNodes = queryElementsWithFilter(
    'div',
    node => !textTokens.includes(node.textContent)
)

unmatchedNodes.forEach(div => div.classList.add('none'))
```

Comment: Hi Xion 14, Thank you for the help. I went with the first one, because atleast for me it is easier to understand. Your code is a bit two advanced for me at this moment. Although I am going to experiment with it to understand it better. 

I appreciate the help though =)

Comment: Np.
Try to run each part of the code in the console of devtools to understand step by step what is happening.
But the only thing you need to get from this is that we have a function `queryElementsWithFilter` which gets elements based on the `css selector` with give it and then `filter` the `elements array` based on the `callback` of the 2nd parameter.
After that we can now filter the `<div>` with specific textContent and do whatever with them and also we can get those elements by applying the opposite filter.